# How to get dynamic selected value from dynamic view in android?

Tags: android, checkbox

[image]

How to get selected checkbox value from dynamic created checkbox in linearlayout.
please help me out.

Comment: You asked a same question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994901/how-to-get-dynamic-created-checkbox-selected-value-from-the-view-position-in-and. Flagged as duplicate

Comment: yes but Sir find no response there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use on CheckedChange listner on the checkbox.

Example: chkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                //Do operations when checked
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: thanx for quick reposne but i used this code but its replace first selected value .i want to both selelcted value in the arryalist.

Comment: and please se my previous same question code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994901/how-to-get-dynamic-created-checkbox-selected-value-from-the-view-position-in-and